# ngCookies saved in chrome but not in android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I use angularjs 1.3.0 beta6 (html5/js/cordova android app) and i have a problem: in browser, ngCookies works good, but in my android application, it's doesnt' work :/ (cookies are not saved in android app) This is my code :

```
function CookiesCtrl($scope, $cookies) {
    // cookie notifications
    if (!$cookies.notifications) {
        $cookies.notifications = "noactivate";
    }
    $scope.cookieNotificationsValue = $cookies.notifications;

    // ng-click
    $scope.clickNotificationsCookie = function() {
        if ($scope.cookieNotificationsValue == "activate") {
            $scope.cookieNotificationsValue = "noactivate";
        } else {
            $scope.cookieNotificationsValue = "activate";
        }
        $cookies.notifications = $scope.cookieNotificationsValue;
    }
}
```

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache cordova or phonegap doesn't support cookies. You will have to use localStorage.

**Example local storage usage**

Getting the keyname

```
var keyName = window.localStorage.key(0);
```

Setting an item

```
window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

Getting an item

```
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Removing an item

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("key");
```

Clearing the local storage

```
window.localStorage.clear();
```

**A note for windows phone 7:** Dot notation is not available, so be sure to use setItem or getItem rather than access keys directly from the storage object, as in window.localStorage.someKey.